# c# linq Groupby query ignoring Where on bool

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable and am trying to first filter with .Where on a bool and then GroupBy like this

```
int someInt = orderEditorViewModel.EditOrderFitters.Where(f => f.Delete == false).GroupBy(f => f.OrderFitter.Person).Count();
```

EditOrderFitters is a List of

```
    public class EditOrderFitter
    {
        [Display(Name = "Delete?")]
        public bool Delete { get; set; }
        public bool Added { get; set; }  // this is hidden
        public OrderFitter OrderFitter { get; set; }
    }
```

But the query includes EditOrderFitter even when Delete is true

I used this longwinded workaround to filter out first

```
List<EditOrderFitter> notDeletedOrderFitters = new List<EditOrderFitter>();
      foreach (EditOrderFitter e in orderEditorViewModel.EditOrderFitters)
      {
          if (!e.Delete)
          {
              notDeletedOrderFitters.Add(e);
          }
      }
```

And then:

```
int someInt = notDeletedOrderFitters.GroupBy(f => f.OrderFitter.Person).Count();
```

That works, but what's wrong with the

```
.Where(f => f.Delete == false)
```

in the first linq query. I also tried this:

```
int someInt = orderEditorViewModel.EditOrderFitters.Where(f => !f.Delete).GroupBy(f => f.OrderFitter.Person).Count();
```

but again the list wasn't filtered

Apologies everyone, I was looking at the LHS of this if statement to test for duplicate entries in a list when I should have been looking at both

```
if (orderEditorViewModel.EditOrderFitters.Where(f => f.Delete == false).GroupBy(f => f.OrderFitter.Person).Count() < orderEditorViewModel.EditOrderFitters.Where(f => f.Delete == false).Count())
```

Thanks for the replies and comments!
I forgot to put the delete on both sides

Comment: Is it EF or in-memory collection?

Comment: The loop should do exactly the same as `orderEditorViewModel.EditOrderFitters.Where(f => !f.Delete).ToList()`.

Comment: It does, my mistake, I've edited the question.   Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just reproduced your situation and it gives me the correct result, You can check to live [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FM0DS5)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702370/c-sharp-linq-groupby-query-ignoring-where-on-bool

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var orderEditorViewModel = new 
        {
            ParentName = "xyz",
            EditOrderFitters = new [] 
            {
                new EditOrderFitter { Delete = true, OrderFitter = new OrderFitter { Id = 1, Person = "1" } },

                new EditOrderFitter { Delete = false, OrderFitter = new OrderFitter { Id = 1, Person = "2" } },

                new EditOrderFitter { Delete = false, OrderFitter = new OrderFitter { Id = 1, Person = "2" } },

                new EditOrderFitter { Delete = false, OrderFitter = new OrderFitter { Id = 1, Person = "3" } }
            }
        };

        var result = orderEditorViewModel.EditOrderFitters.Where(f => !f.Delete).GroupBy(f => f.OrderFitter.Person);
        foreach(var item in result)
            Console.WriteLine("" + " Count: " + item.Count());

    }

    public class EditOrderFitter
    {

        public bool Delete { get; set; }
        public bool Added { get; set; }
        public OrderFitter OrderFitter { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderFitter 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Person { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: It works, my mistake, I've edited the question.   Thank you! This helped me open my eyes and see the error.